# validateOptions gets error

Tags: google-apps-script

The validateOptions clienthandler option doesn't work. It gives always an error.
Is there smth wrong with this method ?

```
function doGet() {
  var mc = new Array();
  mc[0]='h';
  mc[1]='ho';
  mc[2]='hou';
  mc[3]='hous';
  mc[4]='house';
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var rech = app.createTextBox();
  var result = app.createLabel('Match').setVisible(false);
  var ch = app.createClientHandler().validateOptions(rech, mc).forTargets(result).setVisible(true);
  rech.addKeyUpHandler(ch);
  app.add(rech);
  app.add(result);
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's definitely something wrong with it. I can always reproduce this problem as well, and you code seems fine. You should open a report on Apps Script [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

By the way, as a workaround until they solve it. You can always use the `validateMatch` method as a replace of `validateOptions`, it's just more difficult for those who don't know regex. Here's an example using your snippet:

```
var ch = app.createClientHandler().validateMatches(rech, '^h(o(u(se?)?)?)?$').forTargets(result).setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I can confirm this is an error on Google's side. I've opened a defect on the issue tracker so you can follow the status: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1339